# What's the way of passing a pointer from application file to driver HAL file that contains interrupt handler?

Tags: stm32, c, embedded

So there's a static pointer inside `hal.c` that stores a reference to the pointer being passed in from `app.c`, but having a separate function to do so seems a bit off to me though it works.

```
// hal.c
static volatile I2C_Struct *i2cHandle_p;

void SetPointer(I2C_Struct *i2cHandle) {
    i2cHandle_p = i2cHandle;
}

int ReadValues_IT() {
  ...
}

void IRQ_Handler(void) {
  ...
}

// app.c
SetPointer(i2cHandle);  // i2cHandle points to I2C_Struct struct in main.c
ReadValues_IT();
```

Comment: I suspect that you should actually be doing " `I2C_Struct i2cHandle;
SetPointer(&i2cHandle);` in app.c, since what you have there will probably pass a NULL pointer (unless you initialize `i2cHandle` somewhere else.

Comment: - and if you have even the 1st level of optimization enabled in your compiler then that function will almost certainly be optimized away. It purpose is probably to prevent you from accidentally modifying the HAL driver's version of the pointer to the handle in your code somehow.

Comment: actually I should remove the initialization of the pointer in app.c since that's not what's really happening. I pass i2cHandle from main but didn't show it here. @brhans

Comment: but I don't see why I'd be passing `&i2cHandle`

Comment: *Somewhere* in your code you need a `I2C_Struct i2cHandle;` (the full struct, not a pointer), and after that you pass a pointer to it with `&i2cHandle` to whatever needs a `I2C_Struct *` parameter. You need to have a `I2C_Struct` structure for the actual 'handle' to store whatever goes in there.

Comment: @brhans - yes, that's already done and not a point of concern here. just curious as to what should be the right approach towards passing from app to HAL file

Comment: Isn't this a purely opinion-based programming question? It does seem to relate to STM32 and mimic the I2C HAL it has.

Comment: You should probably not have some "I2C struct" outside the I2C driver. The HAL should only deal with abstract data. I'd rather expect to find functions such as `void i2c_write(const uint8_t* data, size_t size)`. What's this struct doing, does it contain settings or does it point straight into the register map?

Comment: @Lundin - well I am populating this struct with user-defined variables including slave address, SCL speed, ack bit. the struct contains a reference for both pointers to user-defined struct and a pointer to a struct containing I2C relevant registers

Comment: @xyf Then why spill that struct outside the driver? Populate it through an init function. If there's just 1 single instance of I2C in your MCU, then you can implement the driver as a singleton with 1 `static` instance of the struct. If you need multiple instances, use a static memory pool, optionally together with "opaque type".

Comment: So you're using move the `I2C_Init()` inside the HAL driver (which I think makes sense) and call it from with user-defined parameters? @Lundin

Comment: So you mean...***